# Merging dataframe tables using two keys

Tags: python, join, pandas

I am trying to merge two tables together where one table is the data set and another explains test results in more details based on two keys from the first table. Data table

results_items:

```
Test ID | Vehicle ID | Test Class ID | Test Result | RfR ID
17           28             2               F          530
22           33             2               P          548
44           49             4               F          7003
52           54             4               F          8553
```

Second Table

item_detail

```
RfR ID  Test Class ID    RfR Desc Marker                     RfR Insp Man Desc         
4               1        missing                             an obligatory lamp missing     
4               2        missing                             an obligatory lamp missing     
5               1        damaged and function impaired       so damaged or deteriorated that its function is impaired
```

I am trying to merge them using inner join on RfR ID and Test Class ID so that each row in the first table has a description associated with it it like so:

```
Test ID | Vehicle ID | Test Class ID | Test Result | RfR ID  |   RfR Insp Man Desc
17           28             2               F          530       an obligatory lamp missing
22           33             2               P          548       an obligatory lamp missing
44           49             4               F          7003      so damaged or deteriorated that its function is impaired
52           54             4               F          8553      so damaged or deteriorated that its function is impaired
```

I tried using the following logic:

```
results_items_desc = pd.merge(
    results_items,
    item_detail,
    how = 'inner',
    on = ['Test Class ID','RfR ID']
)
```

As this is what I would do in SQL, however the output table is empty. My only theory is that it could be something to with the order of columns, however this has never affected my results in sql

Comment: Maybe there are different columns names (e.g. `space` in the end of column name). What is `print results_items.columns` and `print item_detail.columns` ? Or maybe there are different `dtypes` of merging columns. Check  `print results_items.dtypes` and `print item_detail.dtypes`

Comment: Are you sure that you have common values in both columns in both dfs? do you get a df if you change `how='outer'`?

Comment: @jezrael it looks like the join works on RfR ID but not on test class id if I try them separately. I checked data types and RfR ID is an int64, whereas test class id are objects in both tables.

Comment: Are `types` equal? check it `print type(results_items.iloc[0,2])` and `print type(item_detail.iloc[0,1])` - first number in `iloc` function is row position and  second number is column position (starts with 0) or  `print type(results_items.loc[17,'Test Class ID'])` and `print type(item_detail.loc[4,'Test Class ID'])`

Comment: @jezrael One is a string and another is a long. Anything I can do about it?

Comment: You can cast it to `string` by `df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype(str) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916910/merging-dataframe-tables-using-two-keys?noredirect=1#comment59497052_35916910) is with different `types` of merging columns.

Solution is casting column to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
results_items['Test Class ID'] = results_items['Test Class ID'].astype(str)
```

or:

```
item_detail['Test Class ID'] = item_detail['Test Class ID'].astype(str)
```